# Сортировка списка с сохранением позиций элементов с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list

Есть список:

```
lst = ['hello', '3', 'apple', 'boy', '2', 'ball', 'play', '6']
```

Могу отсортировать но без сохранения позиций элементов.

Подскажите как отсортировать данный список что бы получить такой результат:

```
lst1 = ['apple', '2', 'ball', 'boy', '3', 'hello', 'play', '6']
```

Comment: а какая логика вставки чисел? Мне кажется легче разбить на 2 списка, а потом по двум пройтись и слить их в один.

Comment: что значит сортировать с сохранением позиций элементов?

Comment: @TEA  это значит что есть не отсортированный список в котором есть как строки(S) так и числа(D): [S, D ,S, S, D, S, S, D]. После сортировки необходимо что бы порядок строки и чисел в списке остался прежним [S, D ,S, S, D, S, S, D]

Comment: Всё равно не понял. Почему в отсортированном списке `hello` стоит после `play`?

Comment: @andreymal извините за ошибку исправил

Comment: Наверное, нужно запомнить позиции строк и чисел, вытащить в два списка для строк и для чисел, отсортировать их. После собрать в новый список с использованием запомненных ранее позиций. Я правильно понял алгоритм?

Comment: @gil9red да звучит логично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
lst = ['hello', '3', 'apple', 'boy', '2', 'ball', 'play', '6']

lst_pos = [item.isalpha() for item in lst]
print(lst_pos)  # [True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False]

lst_str = sorted(item for item in lst if item.isalpha())
print(lst_str)  # ['apple', 'ball', 'boy', 'hello', 'play']

lst_num = sorted(item for item in lst if not item.isalpha())
print(lst_num)  # ['2', '3', '6']

new_lst = []

for value in lst_pos:
    if value:
        new_lst.append(lst_str.pop(0))
    else:
        new_lst.append(lst_num.pop(0))

print(new_lst)  # ['apple', '2', 'ball', 'boy', '3', 'hello', 'play', '6']
```